# Como sombrear un registro de tabla al hacer click en el y despintar al hacer click en otro registro con Vue

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, vue.js, tablas

Estoy trayendo data del servidor en un arreglo y los pinto usando vfor. Ya tengo un boton para modificar un registro especifico, sin embargo quiero que el registro al que hago click se sombree para que se sepa cual registro se esta actualizando. Cabe aclarar que ya puse el hover para cada registro, pero como se sabe se aplica solo cuando el cursor esta encima.

Estoy usando vue 2. Esta es mi tabla.

```
 <tbody  v-on:click="seleccionar">
      <tr ref="record" class="record" v-for="record in pageOfItems" :key="record.Item_id">
        <td ref="record">{{ record.Item_id  }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.CodigoArticulo }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.Categoria }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.Marca }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.DescripcionArticulo }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.PC_Maniuco }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.PC_Lubrimac }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.PC_DiezMinutos }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.PC_Biogas }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.PC_Machine }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.StockPrincipalManiuco }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.StockTiendaManiuco }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.StockPrincipalLubrimac }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.StockTiendaLubrimac }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.StockPrincipalDiezMinutos }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.StockTiendaDiezMinutos }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.StockPrincipalBiogas }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.StockTiendaBiogas }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.StockPrincipalMachine }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.StockMachine }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.StockTotalPrincipal }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.StockTotalTienda }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.StockTotal }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.UnidadMedida }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.Equivalencia }}</td>
        <td>{{ record.Ubicacion }}</td>
      </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Y se ve algo asi:

[image: Esos son los registros, al hacer click en uno quiero que se sombree para posteriormente hacer click en modificar]

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero que utilices una variable para almacenar el id del registro seleccionado. Al hacer clic en un `tr` se actualiza el valor de esta variable que se utilizará para aplicar condicionalmente una clase a `tr` (para cambiar el color de fondo)

Compruébalo:

```
<tbody v-on:click="seleccionar">
   <tr ref="record" class="record" v-for="record in pageOfItems" :key="record.Item_id" v-on:click="selectedItemId = record.Item_id" v-bind:class="{ 'bg-gray': selectedItemId === record.Item_id }">
      <td ref="record">{{ record.Item_id  }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.CodigoArticulo }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.Categoria }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.Marca }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.DescripcionArticulo }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.PC_Maniuco }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.PC_Lubrimac }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.PC_DiezMinutos }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.PC_Biogas }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.PC_Machine }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.StockPrincipalManiuco }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.StockTiendaManiuco }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.StockPrincipalLubrimac }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.StockTiendaLubrimac }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.StockPrincipalDiezMinutos }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.StockTiendaDiezMinutos }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.StockPrincipalBiogas }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.StockTiendaBiogas }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.StockPrincipalMachine }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.StockMachine }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.StockTotalPrincipal }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.StockTotalTienda }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.StockTotal }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.UnidadMedida }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.Equivalencia }}</td>
      <td>{{ record.Ubicacion }}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Hola. Revise tu solucion y la aplique pero no me funciono. sin embargo por la idea tambien pienso que deberia funcionar. Alguna otra sugerencia? Gracias.

Comment: ¿No funcionó en absoluto? ¿Inspeccionaste el código para verificar que la clase `bg-gray` no se añade a `tr`? Lo pregunto porque puede ocurrir que el `td` tenga un color de fondo para que no se vea el color del `tr`. Otra posibilidad es que la función `select` tenga un `preventDefault`. ¿Lo tiene?

Comment: No funciona. Para descartar hice que se imprimera por pantalla el id de cada registro, y si lo pinta, es decir parece que el problema esta en el v-bind:class.

Comment: ¿Y qué ocurre cuando se imprimen lado a lado `selectedItemId` y `record.Item_id`? Es difícil sin ver más código. ¿Puedes compartir un jsfiddle con más código?

Comment: el jsfiddle acepta single file components de Vue? Porque lo intente pero no me salia como esperaba